# Asp Buttons not adding to text box

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a multiline textbox, `txtPostContest` and several buttons that can be clicked to add an HTML tag to the text box (it's for people who won't know any HTML themselves).

However, the buttons only add text once, and after one is clicked none of the others will add text either.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <label>Post Content:</label>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnBold" runat="server" Text="Bold" Width="90px" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnItal" runat="server" Text="Italics" Width="90px" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLink" runat="server" Text="Link" Width="90px" /> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnImage" runat="server" Text="Image" Width="90px" />
</div>
<div>
    <asp:TextBox id="txtPostContent" runat="server" Width="600px" Height="400px" TextMode="MultiLine" />
</div>
```

**VB.Net**

```
Partial Class blogmanager
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim bold As String = " <strong> </strong> "
Dim ital As String = " <em> </em> "
Dim img As String = " <img src=&quot;PASTE IMAGE FILE HERE&quot; alt=&quot;TYPE ALTERNATE TEXT HERE&quot; height=&quot;250&quot; width=&quot;300&quot;> "
Dim link As String = "<a href=&quot;PASTE HYPERLINK HERE&quot;>PASTE LINK TEXT HERE</a>"

 Protected Sub btnBold_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBold.Click
    txtPostContent.Text += bold
End Sub

Protected Sub btnItal_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnItal.Click
    txtPostContent.Text += ital
End Sub

Protected Sub btnLink_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLink.Click
    txtPostContent.Text += link
    txtPostContent.Text = txtPostContent.Text.Replace("&quot;", ControlChars.Quote)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnImage_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnImage.Click
    txtPostContent.Text += img
    txtPostContent.Text = txtPostContent.Text.Replace("&quot;", ControlChars.Quote)
End Sub
```

I can't see the problem in the simple `text += string` method but obviously it's no good. Is there a more effective way to bung some text into an existing textbox?

Comment: not secure to set those content to textbox... and can u try to txtPostContent.Text +=Html.Encode(img) ?

Comment: The content of the strings doesn't seem to matter too much, it's just that once any of the buttons are clicked, all four stop working.

Answer (score 0):

If you click any button such as Bold first, it would work and display
  .

But any other click would result an error.  For instance when you click italics button

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txtPostContent="   ").

The culprit is the text you set in the textarea ().  It's potentially dangerous text.
You may want to google for the cross site scripting for details.

Once you put HttpUtility.HtmlEncode function call on all text, the error would be gone.  For instance
    txtPostContent.Text += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(bold)

You can add tag validateRequest="false" in your <%@ page. but this is highly NOT recommended!!!

Comment: This works, mostly. Except now it won't replace the &quot; with quote marks.